# Other trig functions

Tags: trigonometry

So while I was researching on some trig functions I realized, are there more functions than the sine, cosine, tangent, secant, cosecant and cotangent? Are they still used today? If not, when and why were they used?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There were *lots* of other functions associated to triangles and circles that used to be, and are no longer, in common use; for example, the [versine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine).  It's impossible to give an exhaustive list without a definition of "trigonometric function", though.

Comment: What I mean by "trigonometric function" is anything ratio on the unit circle or on a triangle.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a function? Perhaps you stumbled upon the hyperbolic trigonometric functions like cosh, sech, tanh. These come up in hyperbolic geometry, but they don't likely aren't taught in introductory courses because hyperbolic geometry is not taught in introductory courses.

Comment: A triangle has three sides. There are six ways to form a ratio of two of the sides ($a/b$, $a/c$, $b/a$, $b/c$, $c/a$, $c/b$). In a right triangle, these give the six trig functions.

Comment: Understood, Neil?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not responding.

Comment: Yeah I understand. Sorry for not responding.